# Incorporating localStorage in a more complicated scenario (save multiple arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I'm trying to implement local storage into my program.

Initially, the program was simple and had only 1 array to save. That array served as the container and the container then fed to #1 - the display output and to #2 - the console output...

[old simpler program](http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/sKadX/26/)

```
pseudo-code to make the red box go away...
```

The above link eventually worked - as you can see on line 54 of the JS, as soon as a new entry is entered into the input box, the updated container was then saved to localStorage. And then upon returning to the site, per line 11 - if upon the initial loading of the program the saved localStorage container doesn't match the initial array, then the saved container is used.

However, I've changed the program drastically so that there are now multiple options to choose from and thus multiple arrays. Whichever option/array is chosen becomes the main container, and the main container still feeds out to the display output and the console output. See the updated program below...

[multiple arrays = more complicated program](http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/L3WyW/9/)

```
pseudo-code
```

The problem is that I am now having a difficult time figuring out how to implement localStorage on this new updated program. It was much easier previously when I only had 1 array to test against. Now, I can't just save the container any time a new entry is inputted (or removed) because the container can be any 1 of the 6 options.

Does anyone have any general ideas/pointers/suggestions as to what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (maybe not the most efficient) option would be to use an array of arrays. If before you had:

```
var container = ["a", "b", "c"];
localStorage.setItem("container", JSON.stringify(container));
```

You'd now have:

```
var container = [
   ["a", "b", "c"],
   ["d", "e", "f"]
];
localStorage.setItem("container", JSON.stringify(container));
```

Then for getting a single one in your new code, you'd just do:

```
var container = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('container'));  //The same as before
var firstItem = container[0];
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Hey @Edgar Villegas Alvarado thanks for the help. I'm trying to implement your guys' help but I'm either really far off or really close (prob really far off). Here's where I'm at http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/L3WyW/11/ Any suggestions as to where I'm messing up?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a JSON object with multiple arrays, and save the entire stringified object in a localStorage variable instead of that single-dimensional array. It could even have a parameter referencing the selected container, and could be structured something like:

```
var containers = {
    selectedContainer: "container1",
    container1: ["text","contents","of","container1"],
    container2: ["text","contents","of","container2"],
    container3: ["text","contents","of","container3"],
    container4: ["text","contents","of","container4"],
    container5: ["text","contents","of","container5"],
    container6: ["text","contents","of","container6"]
}
```

Content could then be pushed and popped to each of these container arrays, and the entire object saved in the single localStorage variable:

```
containers.container1.push("additional contents"); 
localStorage['containers'] = JSON.stringify(containers);

obj = JSON.parse(localStorage['containers']);
```

You could then reference the selected array with the selectedContainer parameter:

```
var container = (obj[obj.selectedContainer])
```

Comment: I think your answer is genius @Paul Geronca, however, the person who's attempting to implement your answer... not so much. haha. Any thoughts on what I could possibly be doing wrong??? I thought I did a good job of implementing your recommendations, but now nothing is displaying in the either the console or the main display - I'm not sure if I'm improperly loading the local storage or improperly saving or if I just have improper syntax in general... your help would be greatly appreciated thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/L3WyW/13/